# Missing number in sorted array

Tags: c

This code is designed to find the missing element in the sorted array, but it fails the second test. What is my error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int a[] = { 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
int b[] = { 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
int c[] = { 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int d[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 };
int e[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int findMissing(int *a, int len) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = len - 1;
    int mid;
    while (R - L > 1) {
        mid = (L + R) / 2;
        if (a[L] - L != a[mid] - mid)
            R = mid;
        else if (a[R] - R != a[mid] - mid)
            L = mid;
    }
    return a[mid] + 1;
}

main() {
    assert( findMissing( a, 5 ) == 6 );
    assert( findMissing( b, 6 ) == 7 );
    assert( findMissing( c, 6 ) == 5 );
    assert( findMissing( d, 6 ) == 8 );
    assert( findMissing( e, 6 ) == 10 );
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please tag only the one you're using.

Comment: `main()` is not valid. It should be `int main()`

Comment: Run one of the failing cases (like `findMissing( b, 6 ) == 7`) in a debugger. It returns `9`, not `7` so you should be able to see when the program does the wrong thing.

Comment: If you want others to find a bug in your code, then you should explain how the algorithm in the code works. This is important not only so that the other person understand your code, but often also helps you to find the problem.

Comment: Your algorithm error is that you assume `a[mid]` will be 1 below the missing number; it can be 1 above in certain cases -- https://i2.paste.pics/22541b0a025bb06f4c8dce6c3898e5c9.png

Comment: Also your 2nd `if` is not needed (it's bad in fact). Every time through the loop you want to **unconditionally** change either `L` or `R`.

Comment: no need to check all elements, a binary search (`O(log n)`) is good

Comment: @pmg yep, nevermind I need to take my breakfast

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm has problems:

- `mid` is used uninitialized if `len <= 2`
- there is no need for the second test, just test the initial boundaries
- furthermore `main()` should have a return type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int a[] = { 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
static int b[] = { 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
static int c[] = { 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
static int d[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 };
static int e[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int findMissing(const int *a, int len) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = len - 1;
    if (len <= 0) {
        // no number
        return 0;
    }
    if (a[0] == a[R] - R) {
        // no missing number
        return a[R] + 1;
    }
    while (R - L > 1) {
        int mid = L + (R - L) / 2;
        if (a[0] != a[mid] - mid)
            R = mid;
        else
            L = mid;
    }
    return a[0] + R;
}

int main() {
    assert( findMissing( a, 5 ) == 6 );
    assert( findMissing( b, 6 ) == 7 );
    assert( findMissing( c, 6 ) == 5 );
    assert( findMissing( d, 6 ) == 8 );
    assert( findMissing( e, 6 ) == 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for editing my code! I forget the boundary conditions!